# Почему regex /[^а-я]/i реагирует на буквы р, т, ч и т.д

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

При валидации на сервере php мне потребовалось проверить строку на наличие символов, которые не входят в русский алфавит, для чего было написано выше указанное выражение, которое возвращает 1, если в строке есть хотя бы один символ, не вписывающийся в диапазон [а-я], регистр при этом не учитывается.

Однако по неведомой мне причине это выражение возвращает единицу, если в строке присутствуют символы "р", "т", "ч", хотя они вписываются в диапазон [а-я].

Это не баг моей версии php, так как онлайн сервисы по тестированию regex тоже выдают этот результат. Что не так в моем понимании регулярных выражений?

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста ссылку на онлайн сервис. Я не разбираюсь в регулярных выражениях, но мне тоже стало интересно посмотреть

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#95828

Comment: 11 лет разработчики на PHP бьются с проблемой UTF-8 :-)

Comment: Время угадывать как выглядит неработающий код.

Comment: Я угадал http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/497765cbbebfc9cecd24694c7162b96bfeefbe2f

Comment: А модификатор `u` разве не то же самое делает?

Comment: @AlexeyTen достаточно флага `u`.

Comment: @teran Ну я на PHP уже лет пятнадцать не писал, мне можно 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вашем случае к выражению следует добавить флаг `u`, отвечающий за юникод, и включить в перечень символов букву `ё`, поскольку она, как ни странно, не входит в указанный диапазон. итого:

```
/[^а-яё]/iu
```